# Django 1.11 media files not displayed

Tags: python, django, sqlite

my urls file

`urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

my settings

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

my template 
`<a href="{{ courrier.piece_jointe.url }}">{{ courrier.objet }}</a>`

everything is set up correctly but when i click the link nothing happened the URL shows up  http:127.0.0.1:8000/media/..... but the page is not redirected to the file content !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In the template (.html file), use src like below:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

source: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Comment: static files are working fine  the problem is in the media files

Comment: Can you share, folder hierarchy for a media file which your cannot see on the url you are redirected? There may be a few reasons for media files. Is the Debug parameter True in your settings.py file? And can you check file permissions?

Comment: Yes DEBUG is True

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes and it worked

`url(r'^$', home.as_view(), name='acceuil'),` 
it was always redirected to home page i changed it to

`url(r'acceuil', home.as_view(), name='acceuil'),`
and i added

`url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',serve, {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT},name='img')`

Thank you guys